# Multiple JPanels inside JDialog, how to control panel re-sizing order?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel

When having multiple JPanels laid out with BorderLayout, what decides which panel should keep its size on the cost of other panels when the containing dialog is re-sized?

In the sample code below, I would like the south panel, containing a JComboBox and JCheckBoxes, to keep its size when the dialog is re-sized.

**Original Size**
[image: Original Size]
**Re-Sized, south panel messed up**
[image: South Panel incorrectly re-sized]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;


public class GrantPrivilegesDialog extends JDialog {
    private JTable queueTable;
    private JComboBox groupComboBox;
    private JCheckBox receiveCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox sendCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox browseCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox viewCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox createCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox deleteCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox modifyCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox purgeCheckBox;
    private TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> queueSorter;
    private DefaultTableModel queueModel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GrantPrivilegesDialog dialog = new GrantPrivilegesDialog();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public GrantPrivilegesDialog() {
        setTitle("Grant Privileges To Group(s)");
        setBounds(100, 100, 866, 461);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        {
            JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
            northPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            {


                queueTable = new JTable();
                //Object[][] rows = null;
                Object[][] rows ={  {"*", "localhost1", "someQueue1"},
                                    {"", "localhost2", "someQueue2"}, 
                                    {"", "localhost3", "someQueue3"}, 
                                    {"", "localhost4", "someQueue4"},
                                    {"", "localhost5", "someQueue5"},
                                    {"", "localhost6", "someQueue6.sdfsdfssdf.sfsdfsdfpweerpowerpoiwer.werjsdgf.sdföw.slksdfsdf"}

                                };
                String[] queueColumnNames = {"","Server","QueueName"};  


                queueModel      = new DefaultTableModel(rows, queueColumnNames){
                    @Override
                    public Class getColumnClass(int colNum) {
                        switch (colNum) {
                            case 0:
                                return String.class;    //Asterisk (*) for dynamic
                            case 1:
                                return String.class;    //Server
                            case 2:
                                return String.class;    //Queue Name
                            default:
                                return String.class;
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                       //all cells false
                       return false;
                    }
                };


                queueTable.setModel(queueModel);
                queueSorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(queueModel);
                queueTable.setRowSorter(queueSorter);
                queueTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

                queueTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(2);
                queueTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(2);
                queueTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(225);
                queueTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(600);
                queueTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

                JScrollPane queueScrollPane = new JScrollPane(queueTable);

                northPanel.add(queueScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                queueScrollPane.setViewportBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Queues", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
                {
                    queueScrollPane.setViewportView(queueTable);
                }
            }
        }
        {
            JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
            getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            southPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            {
                {
                    //JList<? extends E> list = new JList();
                    //panel_1.add(list, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                }
            }
            {
                JPanel privilegesPanel = new JPanel();
                privilegesPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Grant"));
                southPanel.add(privilegesPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                privilegesPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                {
                    JPanel groupListPanel = new JPanel();
                    groupListPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Select Group"));
                    privilegesPanel.add(groupListPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
                    groupListPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    {
                        String[] choices = {"GroupA", "GroupB", "GroupC", "GroupD", "GroupE", "GroupE", "GroupE", "GroupE", "GroupE", "GroupE", "GroupE", "GroupE"};

                        groupComboBox = new JComboBox(choices);
                        groupComboBox.setEditable(true);
                        groupComboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,10));
                        groupComboBox.setSelectedIndex(4);
                        groupListPanel.add(groupComboBox, BorderLayout.EAST);

                    }
                }
                {
                    JPanel privilegesCheckBoxPanel = new JPanel();
                    privilegesCheckBoxPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Privileges"));
                    privilegesPanel.add(privilegesCheckBoxPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
                    privilegesCheckBoxPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
                    {
                        receiveCheckBox = new JCheckBox("receive");
                        receiveCheckBox.setSelected(true);
                        privilegesCheckBoxPanel.add(receiveCheckBox);
                    }
                    {
                        sendCheckBox = new JCheckBox("send");
                        sendCheckBox.setSelected(true);
                        privilegesCheckBoxPanel.add(sendCheckBox);
                    }
                    {
                        browseCheckBox = new JCheckBox("browse");
                        browseCheckBox.setSelected(true);
                        privilegesCheckBoxPanel.add(browseCheckBox);
                    }
                    {
                        viewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("view");
                        privilegesCheckBoxPanel.add(viewCheckBox);
                    }
                    {
                        createCheckBox = new JCheckBox("create");
                        privilegesCheckBoxPanel.add(createCheckBox);
                    }
                    {
                        deleteCheckBox = new JCheckBox("delete");
                        privilegesCheckBoxPanel.add(deleteCheckBox);
                    }
                    {
                        modifyCheckBox = new JCheckBox("modify");
                        privilegesCheckBoxPanel.add(modifyCheckBox);
                    }
                    {
                        purgeCheckBox = new JCheckBox("purge");
                        privilegesCheckBoxPanel.add(purgeCheckBox);
                    }
                }
            }
            {
                JPanel confirmPane = new JPanel();
                southPanel.add(confirmPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                confirmPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
                {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    confirmPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);
                    {
                        JButton grantButton = new JButton("GRANT");
                        panel.add(grantButton);
                        grantButton.setActionCommand("GRANT");
                        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(grantButton);
                        grantButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
                          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

                              System.out.println(receiveCheckBox.isSelected());
                              System.out.println(sendCheckBox.isSelected());
                              System.out.println(browseCheckBox.isSelected());
                              System.out.println(viewCheckBox.isSelected());
                              System.out.println(createCheckBox.isSelected());
                              System.out.println(deleteCheckBox.isSelected());
                              System.out.println(modifyCheckBox.isSelected());
                              System.out.println(purgeCheckBox.isSelected());
                              } 
                        } );
                    }
                    {
                        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("CLOSE");
                        panel.add(cancelButton);
                        cancelButton.setActionCommand("CLOSE");
                    }
                }
                {
                    JLabel errorMessageLabel = new JLabel("");
                    confirmPane.add(errorMessageLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
                }
            }
        }
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(870, 300));
        pack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);` to `getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` and panel with table will be resizable and second panel will be with fixed size:

[image]

Also read about [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). I recommend you to use another layout manager, for example [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), because it is more suitable for complex form.